# Voltage distribution around a dipole for different wavelengths

Tags: electromagnetism, voltage, dipole, antennas

It is well known that the alternating current distribution in a center-fed dipole antenna (black line) is as follows:

[image]

Despite the different wavelengths, the current distributions depicted above all satisfy the boundary condition where the current has zero magnitude at the ends of the dipole.

Q: What is the boundary conditions that must be satisfied for electric potential (voltage) along this dipole and what are the corresponding electric potential  distributions for different wavelengths?

Comment: Wait a minute, why did you vote to close this question without giving a good reason ?  I have the privileges to view close votes and I am surprised that a well illustrated and concretely phrased question receives such reaction.  I hope it is not only because you are unable to answer it.